# Bash Function return values in if ...; then statement

Tags: bash, function, conditional-statements

I'm in the process to enable the firewall on a VM.
Initially the firewall is in a masked state.
I use two functions

```
function status_firewall() {
  RET_VAL=" "
  STATUS=$(systemctl status firewalld)
  MASKED=$(grep -e "masked" <<< $STATUS)
  M_RET=$?

  DEAD=$(grep -e "dead" <<< $STATUS)
  D_RET=$?
  logging "M_RET and D_RET: $M_RET, $D_RET"
  if [ "${M_RET}" -eq "0" ]; then
    RET_VAL=1
  elif [ "${D_RET}" -eq "0" ]; then
    RET_VAL=2
  else
    RET_VAL=0
  fi
  echo ${RET_VAL}
}
```

echo statement prints value "1" if firewall is masked

```
function check_firewall() {
  FIREWALL=$(status_firewall)
  logging "Firewall status in check_firewall: ${FIREWALL}"
  if [ "$(status_firewall)" -eq "0" ]; then
    logging "Firewalld service already running"
    RET_VAL=0
  elif [ "$(status_firewall)" -eq "1" ]; then
     ...
  elif
     ...
  fi
```

I get the correct MASKED and DEAD status value (0, 0) 
   status_firewall() {  ...  }
However, when checking for the return values in 
   check_firewall() {  .. }
I get the following integer error:
   integer expression expected

When checking the return value in:
   check_firewall()
it lists:
   Firewall status: ● firewalld.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null)
   Active: inactive (dead)

How come the first function supposedly returns value "1" but in the second function it lists the return value as the output of the command:
   systemctl status firewalld

Comment: Don't keep calling the function, use `$FIREWALL`.

Comment: What does `logging` do?

Comment: oh goodness, tell me the reason for the failure is the"logging" commands. I removed them and it seems the issue has been fixed, ie, firewall has been unmasked, enambled and started

Comment: None of your functions use return values. They just write to stdout.

Comment: I guess that function writes to stdout, so the output is included in the value of `$(status_firewall)`. Change it to write to stderr.

Comment: Change the script to use return codes. `return 0` on success and then just `if status_firewall; then ...`

Comment: @Barmar, logging is a function where I log the output vie  ```cmd | tee -a file.log```.       I used ```FIREWALL=$(status_firewall)``` just to be able to print the return value from the function, I will remove that one. I want to do the function call and evaluation in the if ... then statement

Comment: But tee writes to stdout, so that part gets captured by the command substitution.

Comment: Use `tee filename 1>&2` so the printed output goes to stderr instead of stdout.

Comment: `-eq` compares two integers. `=` compares two strings.

Answer (score 6):

First, simplify `status_firewall` by using return values instead of writing to standard output, and use pattern matching in a `case` statement instead of calling `grep`.

```
status_firewall() {
    status=$(systemctl status firewalld)
    case $status in
        *masked*) rv=1 ;;
        *dead*)   rv=2 ;;
        *) rv=0 ;;
    esac
    return $rv
}
```

Then  `check_firewall` is just a matter of examining the exit status of `status_firewall`.

```
check_firewall() {
  status_firewall
  case $? in
    0) logging "Firewalld service already running" ;;
    1) ... ;;
    2) ... ;;
  esac
}
```

In fact, you can do away with `status_firewall` altogether:

```
check_firewall() {
  case $(systemctl status firewalld) in
    *masked*) ... ;;
    *dead*) ... ;;
    *) logging "Firewalld service already running" ;;
  esac
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed info. That is some very nice code. Shows me I have a long way to go